# JavaScript TAG Not displaying on Blogger

Tags: javascript, blogger, blogspot

I'm attempting to add a JavaScript tag to my blogger page...

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--
if (window.adgroupid == undefined) {
    window.adgroupid = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);
}
document.write('<scr'+'ipt language="javascript1.1" src=" Date().getTime()+'"></scri'+'pt>');
//-->
</script><noscript><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" border="0" width="1" height="1"></a></noscript>
```

...However the desired advert is not displaying.

Comment: See the code coloring in your example and find the messed quoting ... language attribute is deprecated, How can a date form a valid js filename?

Comment: I'm at a complete loss at this stage, hours spent trying to find some sort of fix.

Comment: The quotations in the `document.write()` line are messed up

Comment: I'm assured that other websites have no issues with this piece of code, seems to be a Blogger specific problem, but, as has already been pointed out, it's all over the place.

Comment: I don't know about web sites, but all browsers will throw "Unterminated string literal" error when trying to parse your code.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to make this code actually work for Blogger?